# Deleting Similar Rows using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a VBA code for an Excel macro so that I can manually trigger the macro to do the following:

In the event that any two rows have:

- Same value in column A
- Same value in Column B
- "apple" in Column C
- Same value in Column D

Then I would like all of those rows to be deleted except the row with the highest value in column E.

As an example, if:

- cell A1 = cell A2
- cell B1 = cell B2
- cell C1 and Cell C2 = "apple"
- cell D1 = cell D2
- Cell E1 = 5 and Cell E2 = 10

Then Row 1 gets deleted and Row 2 remains.

The overall goal is to delete similar rows.

Per a user's suggestions, this process can be aided/simplified by sorting range by c="apple",a,b,d so that rows can be analyzed consecutively.

[Example of Code Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gISlQ.png)

I put together the following code, but I am unfamiliar with the delete row aspect and how to incorporate the highest value, but this was my best shot. The If and elseif statements are questionable.

```
Sub Macro()

Dim a As Range
Dim b As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim d As Range
Dim e As Range

For Each a In Range("A1:A9999")

For Each b In Range("B1:B9999")

For Each c In Range("C1:C9999")

For Each d In Range("D1:D9999")

For Each e In Range("E1:E9999")

If a.Offset(-1, 0) = a And b.Offset(-1, 0) And c.Offset(-1, 0) = c And d.Offset(-1, 0) = d And e.Offset(-1, 0) < e Then Range(a).EntireRow.Delete

ElseIf a.Offset(-1, 0) = a And b.Offset(-1, 0) And c.Offset(-1, 0) = c And d.Offset(-1, 0) = d And e.Offset(-1, 0) > e Then Range(a.Offset(-1, 0)).EntireRow.Delete

Exit For

Next a

Next b

Next c

Next d

Next e

End Sub
```

Comment: This might be easier with a helper column using MAXIFS.

Comment: Actually I realize the code I put together doesn't even make sense... I am working on revising it. The description I wrote is correct, though.

Comment: Your example compares **2 consecutive** rows  is this what you want??

Comment: @BigBen Hmm I am unaware of that - I will look into it!

Comment: @Gary'sStudent It compares any of the rows in the document. Not necessarily consecutive rows.

Comment: Temporarily sorting your range by c="apple",a,b,d would mean all your possible matches are grouped together and can be read once, comparing consecutively, rather than looping through it all over and over..

Comment: @CLR good tip! I will modify the post to state that would be an acceptable pre-step.

Comment: Okay - I added potential if statements that would better fulfill the objective. It doesn't work as is, but I have a feeling it is close.

Comment: Has the second row (linke in your example) always the max-value in column "D". In other words, do you want the max in col D from all rows where the a.m. conditions fit? Which Excel Version do you use, maybe you can use Grouping with PowerQuery i.o. VBA.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it works.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RunMacro()
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long, j As Long
Dim cellA, cellB, cellC, cellD, cellE
Dim Rng As Range
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
cellA = Range("A" & i).Value
cellB = Range("B" & i).Value
cellC = Range("C" & i).Value
cellD = Range("D" & i).Value
cellE = Range("E" & i).Value

For j = LastRow To 2 Step -1
    If Range("A" & j).Value = cellA And Range("B" & j).Value = cellB Then
        If Range("C" & j).Value = cellC And Range("D" & j).Value = cellD Then                  

            If cellE > Range("E" & j).Value Then
                Range("E" & j).EntireRow.Delete
                LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            End If

        End If
    End If
Next j
Next i
            LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            With ActiveSheet
            Set Rng = Range("A1", Range("E1").End(xlDown))
            Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Header:=xlYes
            End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the input! From what I can tell, the only item that would need modified is for column C. The code needs to be specific for rows with the word "apple" in column C. I'm a little unsure how to modify your code to do this...would I change "Range("C" & j).Value = cellC" to "Range("C" & j).Value = "apple"" ?

Comment: yes, you can do that or if you want, you can fill the column C full of "Apple" :)

Comment: Unfortunately I do have to report back that it does not work as intended.... When I run this code once, there was a row that got deleted that had a unique value for column B violating the requirement that column B has to be equal. Also after running the code for a second time, I then lost one of the two remaining rows that had unique values for column D. I just uploaded a picture showing what the code should do to the excel sheet.

Comment: Sorry for delay, could you please try it?

Comment: It seems to be working on my simplified file! I will have a larger data set to test on in about 45 minutes and will report back! Thank you so much!

Comment: So I tested it on the larger file and for columns A-E this works perfectly, but there are additional columns in the larger document. As a result, this ends up mis-matching columns A-E with the remaining columns in the document. So the dilemma becomes how can the code be modified so that the "extra" columns are not mis matched? I can post a screenshot of what I mean in a bit.

Comment: I tested it once again on the bigger file and I seemed to have gotten it to work with a small code modification that was outside the purview of the post so for all intents and purposes, your work seems to be correct. I will test once more again today with another file to verify. For anyone reading, if you have additional colums, you simply change "E1" in Set Rng = Range("A1", Range("E1").End(xlDown)) to include your last column and add in each column numbers in "Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Header:=xlYes"